# Error Autocreating Apex Class: Invalid type: Auth.UserData while configuring Facebook as Auth provider

Tags: community, facebook, auth-provider

I had setup facebook as an auth provider with salesforce communities and it worked very well until a few days ago.

After spending couple of hours with it, I have found that there is a problem with the Registration handler class. When I try to edit and save the same code, I get the following error :

> Error: Compile Error: Invalid type: Auth.UserData at line 2 column 41

I also tried the sample code given here (https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_auth_plugin.htm#apex_auth_plugin_part2) but get the same error.

One strange behaviour i noticed is that when i try to create a new Auth. Provider and select "Automatically create a registration handler template", I get a similar erro complaining about the type :

> Error autocreating Apex Class: Invalid type: Auth.UserData

Can someone please advise why it suddenly stopped working and how can i resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I had another apex class with the same name "Auth". Removing it fixed the problem.